# File format specifications

Tags: binaryfiles

I'd like to know where can I find some reference/manual that explains how to deal with common file formats ( zip, jepg, gif, png, elf binaries, etc) so that i can use them in my programs.

I already know that there are many libraries that would get the work done for me and that wolud do it better than I could ever do, but i'd just like to understand them for fun.

Thanks

Comment: Google is your friend. Seriously! Also the Wikipedia articles on file formats usually all have a link to the official specification at the end.

Comment: I haven't seen anything useful from google and when i look to official ISO specifications from the links on wikipedia it asks me for money to "buy the standard" ... ?    i don't understand if it means that i have to buy a manual or if i can actually "own" it, but I woulden't have money anyways

Comment: https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT